# Need clarification on "print or type clearly in black ink"

Tags: meaning

I was recently filling my scholarship application where I got very confused by this sentence:

> The essay must be clearly typed or printed in black ink

Does that mean that I can fill the application on my computer and then print it with a printer? Or should I only use a black pen to fill this applcation? From the research that I did, some told me that type refers to typewriters which are obsolete nowadays while other told me that type also includes the computer. As a result, I became confused.

Comment: Use black ink whether you fill out the application by hand or by “mechanical” type, ie, a printer.

Comment: You can do it on your computer if it's a form in which you can enter answers, or you can roll it into a typewriter, or use a black-ink pen.

Comment: They are using *print* to distinguish from *write* (using cursive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

Jim made a good argument:

> Printed means hand printed as opposed written in cursive. Filling out by hand is allowed.

But this means that the rule is ambiguously phrased. Either interpretation could be correct.

> The essay must be clearly typed or printed in black ink.

Initially, I understood this to mean:

- **Typed** = using a typewriter
- **Printed** = using a computer and printer

However, due to Jim's addition, there is another equally valid interpretation:

- **Typed** = using a computer (the inclusion of a typewriter is possible but unlikely)
- **Printed** = written by hand, but not in cursive.

If you're going to use a computer anyway, there should be no problem. But if you want to make sure whether handwriting is allowed, I'd contact whoever created the rule and ask for disambiguation.

I'm inclined to believe Jim's variant, mostly because typewriters are so outdated by modern day standards.

However, I've also seen very outdated business documents* that are still being used, which makes it possible that this rule is a remnant from the past and was simply never rephrased.

---

**The most amusing one I've found is the End User License Agreement for the Wii U, which still contains the "please circle the applicable option" remarks in its **digital** form. You're expected to click "I accept", not to print the form and fill it out, but they never changed the agreement's contents to reflect that.*

Comment: Printed means hand printed as opposed written in cursive.  Filling out by hand is allowed.

Comment: @Jim: In that case, I would argue that the phrase is inherently ambiguous. "Printed" can refer to handwritten or computer printing, "typed" could then also refer to either a typewriter or a computer. The seemingly strict rule is somewhat undone by the ambiguous phrasing used.

Comment: It was all about legibility and most people’s cursive was horrible.  They needed it to be readable, and they needed to be able to photocopy it (blue didn’t copy very well) When this phrase was put into service “printing” unambiguously referred to hand written in unconnected lettering.

Comment: @Jim I know print can mean "write (text) clearly without joining the letters together." but in the "real world",  I would be amazed if they wanted a scholarship application hand-written so I'd go with Flater's first interpretation i.e. Typed = using a typewriter / Printed = using a computer and printer. [Oops, just realised my comment is 12 months late!]

Answer (score 2):

You may use a computer to fill in the application; however, the result must be clear and easy to read for processing, and you must not use any color other than black.